# How to connect to wpa2 enterprise mschapv2?

Tags: wireless, networking, wpa2

My college internet used to work in **12.04**, but now **13.04** refuses to connect to *wpa2 enterprise*.

Answer (score 4):

Might be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1104476

**Workaround**: Remove the line, or change the value from `true` to `false`. Found in the section `[802-1x]`

```
system-ca-cert=true
```

from the configuration file found in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CONNECTION`