# Authentication in wireless network

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.04, authentication

I am authenticating a network using WPA2, but it's not working (it authenticates then turns off)

- OS: Ubuntu 13.04
- Wireless network card : Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300

---

```
$ dmesg:
[ 1248.966666] wlan0: authenticate with 00:20:a6:bb:ff:e1
[ 1248.969571] wlan0: send auth to 00:20:a6:bb:ff:e1 (try 1/3)
[ 1248.986155] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1248.986417]iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 1248.986425] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 1248.988049] wlan0: associate with 00:20:a6:bb:ff:e1 (try 1/3)
[ 1248.990384] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:20:a6:bb:ff:e1 (capab=0x31 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1248.995162] wlan0: associated
[ 1251.042674] wlan0: disassociating from 00:20:a6:bb:ff:e1 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1251.201126] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1251.201392] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:20:a6:bb:ff:e1 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1251.209426] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1251.209433] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1251.209438] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1251.209442] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1251.209446] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1251.209450] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1251.209453] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
root@jafa:~#
```

---

```
$Lshw
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 00
                serial: 00:21:6a:93:b4:48
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.8.0-21-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                resources: irq:47 memory:f4200000-f4201fff
```

---

```
$ iwlist wlan0 genie
wlan0     no generic IE (Operation not supported).
```

---

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 encryption
[sudo] password for josimar:
wlan0     2 key sizes : 40, 104bits
          4 keys available :
        [1]: off
        [2]: off
        [3]: off
        [4]: off
          Current Transmit Key: [1]
```

---

```
$ lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 1101
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at f4200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-21-6a-ff-ff-93-b4-48
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

---

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               12550  1
vboxpci                22896  0
vboxnetadp             25636  0
vboxnetflt             27261  0
vboxdrv               285137  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
parport_pc             27504  0
ppdev                  12817  0
bnep                   17669  2
rfcomm                 37420  0
bluetooth             202069  10 bnep,rfcomm
snd_hda_codec_realtek    63791  1
binfmt_misc            17260  1
uvcvideo               71279  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      12920  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13042  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         39161  1 uvcvideo
videodev               95806  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
joydev                 17097  0
arc4                   12543  2
iwldvm                220185  0
mac80211              526519  1 iwldvm
coretemp               13131  0
snd_hda_intel          38307  5
snd_hda_codec         117580  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80890  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13132  0
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            25114  1 snd_seq_midi
iwlwifi               155077  1 iwldvm
i915                  535507  4
drm_kms_helper         47545  1 i915
snd_seq                51280  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
microcode              18286  0
cfg80211              436177  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
drm                   228750  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              24411  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
psmouse                81038  0
serio_raw              13031  0
lpc_ich                16925  0
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
wmi                    18590  0
snd                    56485  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
jmb38x_ms              17177  0
memstick               15842  1 jmb38x_ms
soundcore              12600  1 snd
video                  18894  1 i915
mac_hid                13037  0
lp                     13299  0
parport                40753  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12484  0
usbhid                 41805  0
hid                    82666  2 hid_generic,usbhid
firewire_ohci          35292  0
sdhci_pci              18158  0
ahci                   25507  4
sdhci                  31824  1 sdhci_pci
firewire_core          61718  1 firewire_ohci
libahci                26108  1 ahci
r8169                  61531  0
crc_itu_t
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the same problem since about a week after upgrading to 13.04.

Found a related bug [here on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1104476).

Please tell Launchpad that the bug affects you! :)

Workaround found here:
[How to connect to wpa2 enterprise mschapv2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285741/how-to-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-mschapv2)

Remove

```
system-ca-cert=true
```

from the configuration file found in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

Wireless works again after removing this!

Comment: system-ca-cert was not present in my configuration under that directory. So, unfortunately this suggest didn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is rather old now, but I was having a similar issue, and I also did not have the `system-ca-certs=true` line in my network configuration. I resolved the issue temporarily by issuing

```
killall wpa-supplicant
```

I don't know why this works, but it does. This answer originated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554584/kernel-wlan0-deauthenticating-from-x-by-local-choice-reason-3), with little explanation.