# Help! WiFi problems with Ubuntu. (Full logs)

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, broadcom

Okay, here's the situation. I have a Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 05) WiFi card, and It really doesn't like my new router; It won't connect, the Wireless manager shows connection animation for a few minutes, then says disconnected. I am sure  the password is correct.

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. I've had Ubuntu on this machine before (Installed using same disk), and with my old router WiFi worked fine. Now I have a new router- an Arris TG1672G modem. I currently am using a USB WiFi Dongle (Which is painfully slow) to use the internet.

This modem outputs two WiFi signals: Wireless_Vic, and Wireless_Vic-5G. (Two different bands, 5G being faster) Both have the same WPA2 Personal key.

OS X and Windows 7 have no problems connecting to either network on the same machine.

In the logs I show an attempt to connect to the Wireless_Vic WiFi.

(Logging instructions from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingNetworkManager)

I can't make much of it, take a look. (USB Dongle removed for logging, Broadcom card only.)

http://pastebin.com/1zvxG7BQ

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you're connecting fine, the router accepts your key and you authenticate successfully.  But then on line 554 you fail to obtain an IPv4 address from the router, which is odd because it looks like you successfully obtained an IPv6 address.  See if anything in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/342666/205638) helps, specifically disabling IPv6 or setting a static IP for IPv4.  [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/396112/205638) might also be relevant since you have a Broadcom card.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed enter this in the terminal it might work:

```
  rfkill unblock soft
  rfkill unblock hard
  lsmod wlan0
  lsusb -s  udevadm
```

and then scan for Google whit nmap if it is installed type this in the terminal:

```
 nmap -v -A Google.com
```

and it might work fine this way.