# kernel: wlan0: deauthenticating from x by local choice (reason=3)

Tags: wireless, networking

My wifi card worked fine earlier today. Now it does not work anymore. I also tried using an external USB wifi card and I got the same error:

```
kernel: wlan0: deauthenticating from x by local choice (reason=3)
```

I have tried restarting network (/etc/init.d/networking restart), unloading/reloading the wifi kernel modules, disabled and reenabled wifi in NetworkManager. None of these worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None of those kills wpa_supplicant (oddly enough: If I unload all wifi modules and disable wifi you would think wpa_supplicant would take the hint). So:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
```

and then everything works.

Comment: Why does this work? The solution was also posted [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/577827/289003) and links back to this answer, but no one has said why it works. (Unfortunately it didn't work for me)

Comment: I too would love to know why this works (but unlike @Nateowarmi it does work for me). A reboot doesn't fix it but this does, it's weird.

Comment: http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2013/01/14/about-deauthenticating-from-by-local-choice-reason3/ suggests `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`, no idea if that kills wpa_supplicant as well