# Wi-Fi connection problem with Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, atheros

I've switched my HP Pavilion dv6 from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS several months ago and had no problems whatsoever connecting to the internet via wifi. However, about two days ago, connection speed started to fluctuate greatly or stop working altogether at times. Rebooting helped at first but now it's dead, nothing helps. I reinstalled Ubuntu (because I was planning on doing it for another purpose and I thought I shouldn't loose time trying to fix the connection when a clean reinstall was going to do that anyway) but it didn't fix the problem. The wireless access point shows a valid connection but I can't actually connect. I have spent several hours trying solutions suggested for similar questions on this forum but nothing worked. So I've finally used the wireless script provided here and these are my readings http://paste.ubuntu.com/10236572/
Please advise! I can use the ethernet connection only for a limited period of time..
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the router settings from channel auto or 1 to channel 2 or 3 as there are a few other access points on channel 1.  Also change encryption to WPA2-AES only with no WPA, WEP or TKIP.  You can see the results using `iwlist scan` and then look at the data for your access point, ideally you want to see this

```
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

CCMP = AES

The issue may have been caused by a kernel update, did you attempt the 'Try Ubuntu without installing to see if the wifi is stable?  If so, booting into an older kernel may help

Comment: So I first tried booting into an older kernel but that didn't do much. Instead,the changes you suggested for my router seemed to have resolved the problem for good. So I can only tank you very much for them. But the _iwlist_ reading looks like this:http://paste.ubuntu.com/10243343/

Comment: Still looks like WPA is enabled but no TKIP, if it has problems again disable to WPA and hopefully the WPA2 will be the only thing left, but your router might not allow it

Answer (score -1):

Please run following commands:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1 ps_enable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
modprobe -r ath9k
modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1
modprobe ath9k ps_enable=1
```

Then, reboot your system to take effect.This solution worked fine for me. To get more options, have a look at [reynhout's chrx-repository](https://github.com/reynhout/chrx/blob/master/dist/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf).