# Computer loses connection, then can't see any wireless networks

Tags: networking, wireless

I just started using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after a lifetime of using windows. I have started getting used to it, but I'm still not very experienced. I think I have been using Ubuntu for at least a month now, but this problem only started 2 days ago.

Basically everything would be fine, then all of a sudden I'm offline and I can't see any networks when I open the networks tab. A restart would fix this 90% of the time. When it doesn't work after a restart, I just restart again :D.

So it is getting annoying now since I have to restart 3-4 times a day, and I would really like to know a fix for this.

*I tried restarting the network manager, didn't work.

```
service network-manager restart
```

Edit 1:
output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NB037H 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [AR9002WB-1NGCD] [1a3b:2c37]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output

Comment: Have you tried this answer? http://askubuntu.com/a/585743/32548