# WiFi is not connecting in Ubuntu 14.04, just asking for authentication multiple times

Tags: networking, wireless

I am trying to connect with WiFi, and its just asking for passwords every 5 seconds. it was working fine previously, but after the kernel upgrade HWE WiFi is not able to connect, while Ethernet is working fine.

Please have a look at the [WiFi script information](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tasn205u8sgiza/wireless-info.txt?dl=0).

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/554584/kernel-wlan0-deauthenticating-from-x-by-local-choice-reason-3 Can you try their solution and see if that helps?

Comment: i tired this as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the network you have previously connected to uses WPA encryption. If this is a router over which you have administrative control, I suggest you check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, I have better luck with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us hear your results.

Comment: Sorry for late reply i tried all the steps as explained but it didn't worked.

Comment: Also i tried to connect in my university the wifi works fine wth no security and with PEAP security. I am not able to figure out that is the problem in my Home network.