# Unable to select None for CA Certificate when connecting to university Wi-Fi

Tags: networking

Recently switched to Ubuntu (20.04.1 LTS) on my personal laptop and am trying to connect to my university Wi-Fi following their instructions for Ubuntu-based systems. On the instructions, we are supposed to leave "None" as the CA certificate option, yet the connect button is greyed out when I do this.

My university uses WPA/PEAP/Version 0/MSCHAPv2.

Does anyone know how to connect without selecting a CA certificate (No CA Certificate required is also incorrect - supposedly the CA certificate is provided dynamically when you connect)?

I've seen this to be possible on Ubuntu, a series of screenshots with a security pop-up asking if the user wishes to not select a CA Certificate.
[I've included an image of the connect to wi-fi screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEmzR.png)

I have tried the answers to similar questions:
[Can't connect to wpa2-enterprise networks like eduroam with certificate in 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699498/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-networks-like-eduroam-with-certificate-in-15-10)

and [How to connect to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise wifi networks that don't use a CA_Certificate, like Eduroam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/how-to-connect-to-wpa2-peap-mschapv2-enterprise-wifi-networks-that-dont-use-a-c)

to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it still grayed out when you type in your user name and password?

Comment: Yeah, when I enter all the fields provided (including domain, username, and password) it's still greyed out. The only way to connect is by selecting "No CA Certificate required" although I'm told this is incorrect and the subsequent connection does not work.@OrganicMarble

Comment: But have you tried it or was simply told it wont work?